# Silverlight "Ctrl + Enter" key handler compatibility

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser, keyboard-shortcuts

We are planning on using the key combination of "Ctrl + Enter" to generate new rows in grids throughout our application.  This key combination doesn't appear to be reserved, but we were just wondering if anyone knows of any browsers that this would present a problem in before we go to production?

Thanks in advance.
Ryan.

Comment: Why not just 'enter'? Keyboard shortcuts cause all sorts of issues on devices.

Comment: Unfortunately enter is taken by the Grid Control we use for exiting the edit mode of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether mobile devices are, or will be of interest to you. I suspect that combination might be a bit tricky on a touch screen regardless of browser. Other than that I believe it would be a valid keyboard combination.

Andy.